# Свойство -webkit-font-smoothing

Tags: css, шрифты

Скажите, пожалуйста, что означает css-свойство `-webkit-font-smoothing`, какие значения оно может принимать, где можно найти документацию по нему.

В частности интересует какие эффекты даёт следующая строчка:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/blog/sglazhivanie-shriftov-v-safari

Comment: @soledar10, спасибо, хорошая статья